# Connecting to a password protected Web Service with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am trying to connect to a Web Service which is password protected and I can't figure out what the Guid is for.
I have a basic understanding of SOAP and will be using PHP's SoapClient.

The following was sent to me:

```
    Guid Login(string Username, string Password)

    string Add(Guid AccessKey, string CompanyCode, string CustomerNumber,
    string Address)
```

The above 'Add' is to add a user to the database after authentication.
If anyone is familiar with SOAP and can help me with the Guid it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably session ID or user ID.

Comment: Thank you. You were right. It is a session ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle I found that as michaJIS said it is a session ID and one lust get this when requesting with the username and password. This Session ID must then be used in all other requests.